# Fourier series piecewise function

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, fourier-series, trigonometric-integrals

Obtain the fourier series on the interval: 
$$[-\pi,\pi]$$
 of the function:

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
 -\pi x&\text{if}\, -\pi \leq x\leq 0\\
  x^2 &\text{if}\ ,   0 <x\leq \pi\\
\end{cases}$$

Solution given by book:
$$S(x) = \frac{5\pi^2}{12}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\frac{3(-1)^n -1}{n^2} \cos{nx}+2 \frac{(-1)^n - 1}{n^3\pi}\sin{nx}\right]$$

basically i'm stuck because I can't get my answer to match the solution given. I'm using the method that $-\pi x$  is an odd function so $a_n= 0$ and then working out $b_n$ using that function. Similarly $x^2$ is even so $b_n = 0$ and using that function to workout an. Can someone provide a step by step solution? or tell me what I'm doing wrong? thank you :)

\begin{align}
  %
  a_{0} &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^2 dx \\
  %
  a_{n} &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^2 \cos \left( {n x} \right) dx \\
  %
  b_{n} &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} -\pi x \sin \left( n x  \right) dx \\
  %
\end{align}

Comment: Hm, don't $-\pi x, x \in [-\pi, 1]$ and $x^2, x \in[0,\pi]$ overlap with each other on $[1,\pi]$? Also, isn't $a_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \,dx$?

Comment: Sorry about that I put the wrong interval. I thought a0 was just an where n = 0?

Comment: Nope, you should check the definition of $a_0$ - it is a result of the multiplication of the fourier series by $cos(mx)$ and integration over $-\pi, \pi$, should be in your textbook. All coeffs involve integration of the function over $[-\pi, \pi]$, so you need to correct your coefficient integrals - you can split them to integrals of $-\pi x$ in $[-\pi,0]$ and $x^2$ over $[0,\pi]$, but you must integrate $f(x)$ over the whole period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it that way because neither $-\pi x$ or $x^2$ are odd or even on the *entire* interval of $[-\pi,\pi]$. They each only take up one half.

You have to integrate the whole thing. **No shortcuts.**

\begin{align} a_0 &= \frac{1}{\pi}\left[-\int_{-\pi}^0 \pi x\ dx + \int_0^{\pi} x^2\ dx \right] \\
a_n &= \frac{1}{\pi} \left[-\int_{-\pi}^0 \pi x \cos (nx)\ dx + \int_0^\pi x^2 \cos(nx)\ dx \right] \\ 
b_n &= \frac{1}{\pi} \left[-\int_{-\pi}^0 \pi x \sin (nx)\ dx + \int_0^\pi x^2 \sin(nx)\ dx \right] 
\end{align}

None of these integrals will go to $0$ since you're always integrating over half the interval. You don't have a symmetric interval in any integration, so nothing simplifies.

There also may or may not be a factor of $1/2$ in the $a_0$ integral depending on how you define your Fourier series. Check your book.